# How to remove from a set after expiration

Tags: java

I have a set of Tokens :

```
   private Set<Token> tokenSeen;
```

Where

```
Token is [id, expirationtime]
```

Each token has a different expirationtime set by client.

So, when expirationtime occurs I want to remove the token from tokenSeen set.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use an ordered set which is ordered by expiration time. Then periodically check the first element and when it expires remove it. Afterwards check the new first element again and remove that as well if expired. Repeat until the (current) first element is not expired (and due to the sort by expiration time all the others should also not be expired yet).

To check periodically you might want to employ a scheduler like Quartz or a timer, depending on your overall architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I want to use a scheduler.. so I ll do some reading and try to implement it.

Comment: @user1180969 If your application runs on an application server like JBoss, Glassfish etc. you'l most probably already have access to a scheduler (Quartz it is for JBoss).

Answer (score 1):

Use an iterator to iterate through all elements in the set and remove any element having an old expiration time. If there are no references to the tokens that you removed, then Java Garbage Collector will clean them from memory when it executes.

```
  Date now = new Date();
  Set<Token> tokenSeen = new HashSet<Token>();
  Iterator<Token> iterator = tokenSeen.iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
     Token token = iterator.next();
     if(token.expirationtime.before(now))
        iterator.remove();
  }
```

Comment: I was thinking of a solution like the one mentioned. But, I was really hoping to use a scheduler.

Comment: You can trigger this code from wherever you want, this is just the code to traverse the set and remove respective items `in Java code`.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to set up a [`DelayQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) to keep track of which elements have expired and remove them.